# right to left string in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Consider below query containing both Persian(a right to left language) and English(a left to right language):

```
SELECT 'نرم افزار SQL سرور'
```

the required result is this string :

سرور SQL نرم افزار

Is there any function or any other way to converting string from ltr to rtl??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is required to add `N` before string literal: `SELECT N'نرم افزار SQL سرور'`. This is needed to correctly interpret contained Unicode characters. ([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx))

Important: In some cases, please avoid using standard copy-paste in order to put SELECT into SSMS command window. This could [affect the RTL/LTR order](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/6b0e1775-defe-4106-a3a0-5c29210811bf/how-to-store-arabic-and-english-in-a-same-column). Instead, try to open correctly composed file using **File > Open**.

And **regarding your comment**:

> the result should be : سرور SQL نرم افزار`

I admit I understand RTL writing system only partially, but from what I can see, Persian words **are put to the output exactly in order as you entered them** (even if reading right to left). Could you show me based on [Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/) or similar standards document why the word order should be changed by SQL Server? Shouldn't be change you expect made by preprocessing on another place, sending expected string form `SELECT N'سرور SQL نرم افزار'`? I see no point why just SQL `SELECT` should perform the change. **If it did, what would happen if you feed result of such a `SELECT` into another `SELECT`? Another transformation?** I have reasons to think that SQL server is interpreting your input technically correctly.

Hint: maybe you can try to surround your RTL text by different [Directional formatting characters](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Directional_Formatting_Characters).

Please try the same `SELECT` with MySQL server at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/6254/0). Different server and technology, but the same result as Microsoft SQL Server gave.

Result from SSMS with MS SQL Server:
[image]

**Conclusion:** in order to get expected result, please form the input accordingly.

**Related:** [Transformation of word order you expected can be done by appropriate settings in user interface.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30886993/2392157)

Comment: @Behnam – answer updated. Please see image with results. I can see that in both cases (A, B) output always exactly corresponds to input. And that is correct. Are you getting different results? If yes, please update the question acccordingly.

Comment: we are one step closer now . this result is correct . but i want Result B for Statement A and Result A for Statement B.

Comment: @Behnam – I understand, but you cannot expect *Result B for Statement A* and *Result A for Statement B*. This is not like SQL Server works. Corresponding output is given for input, no transformations. As you can see, this is true not only for Microsoft SQL Server, but also for other SQL servers – try clicking "SQL Fiddle" link in the answer to test with MySQL server.

Comment: you can try by MS Word. if we change text direction we can expect this result in MS Word. also there is locked functions in crystal report which do this task

Comment: I understand, but MS Word and Crystal Reports are targetted towards good representation of final output (they both print to paper). SQL servers are data processing tools, do not expect any advanced visualization transformations from them (such as RTL processing you mentioned). User input interfaces (forms) and output tools (reports) should do the transformations – not SQL server.

Comment: I am sure that you are enough professional to solve my problem. could you please connect me by team viewer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80746/discussion-between-miroxlav-and-behnam).

Answer (score 1):

When we add digit with english this will again not work following solution will work

SELECT nchar(8234)+ N' 33-M ' + N'کلینک کمرہ نمبر'   +nchar(8236)   +  N'میں تشریف لائیں'